# OpenAPI some unkown values

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm reading this: [OpenAPI 3.0 Tutorial](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/tutorials/openapi-3-tutorial)

If I'm looking on one of the examples, there are some things I can't understand

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Simple API
  description: A simple API to illustrate OpenAPI concepts

servers:
  - url: https://example.io/v1

components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
security:
  - BasicAuth: []

paths:
  /artists:
    get:
      description: Returns a list of artists 
      parameters:
        - name: limit
          in: query
          description: Limits the number of items on a page
          schema:
            type: integer
        - name: offset
          in: query
          description: Specifies the page number of the artists to be displayed
          schema:
            type: integer
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully returned a list of artists
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  required:
                    - username
                  properties:
                    artist_name:
                      type: string
                    artist_genre:
                      type: string
                    albums_recorded:
                      type: integer
                    username:
                      type: string
        '400':
          description: Invalid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:   
                  message:
                    type: string

    #  ----- Added lines  ----------------------------------------
    post:
      description: Lets a user post a new artist
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object 
              required:
                - username
              properties:
                artist_name:
                  type: string
                artist_genre:
                  type: string
                albums_recorded:
                  type: integer
                username:
                  type: string

      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully created a new artist

        '400':
          description: Invalid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:   
                  message:
                    type: string
    #  ---- /Added lines  ----------------------------------------
```

1. Why the response of `/get` contains: `required: username`  ? what is the meaning of this ?
   if I don't want basic authentication, can I remove this line ?
2. Why do we need to write `required: true` for the `requestBody` under the `post` ? It's not basic that `post` contains body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of your questions are:

1. Why the response of /get contains: required: username? what is the meaning of this? if I don't want basic authentication, can I remove this line?
   **Ans:** Username is required means it's mandatory, i.e. response must contain this field with some value in it. It's not associated with basic authentication. So, yes you can remove that line if it is not used by the application.
2. Why do we need to write required: true for the requestBody under the post? It's not basic that post contains body?
   **Ans:** `Required: true` is not mandatory to write here. It's an optional field and post must have a request body. Yeah, you are right. It's a basic thing that posts must have to contain the request body.

If you can have any confusion further then let me know. Thanks